# Can you say "When to use simple and progressive" or do you have to say "When to use simple and when to use progressive"?

Tags: grammar

My question is do you need to include the "when to use" after and?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is valid to use the shorter option, since the "when to use" is implied. I can't remember the grammatical term for it, but I believe it is a type of [clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause).